# createjs - how to completely destroy all traces

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, createjs

I have made an app using JavaScript/createjs, launched in a modal over the current page. However, when I exit the app, there are still remnants of createjs lingering - to the point where if I continually launch/close the app I can exceed the AudioContext limit - suggesting there are 6 (in the browser I'm using) instances of createjs lingering.

I must point out that refreshing the page does work, but will not be an option, nor will using an iframe.

The file is standalone and has all the createjs libraries inside it. My question is, is there a way to completely destroy createjs? I have tried createjs = null, which works to an extent, but listeners still remain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SoundJS, you can remove sounds from memory with the provided APIs, such as [`removeAllSounds`](http://createjs.com/docs/soundjs/classes/Sound.html#method_removeAllSounds). Here is an example:

```
createjs.Sound.removeAllSounds();
```

If you find that this still has the same issues with the AudioContext limit, I recommend logging a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/issues). It is possible that although references to loaded audio are getting cleared out, it is not wiping out the references to the AudioContext it uses.

You could also try wiping out the existing context before you clean up the createjs namespace:

```
createjs.WebAudioPlugin.context = null;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with nulling `createjs` along with all of your own references to any CreateJS objects. You can also call `createjs.Ticker.reset()` to disable the Ticker and Tween, `myStage.enableDOMEvents(false)` to remove the event listeners the stage adds, and `createjs.Sound.stop()` to stop all sounds.